# How to create two horizontal axis labels for same data in excel?

Tags: excel, graph

I would like to add the wavelength as a second horizontal axis below the frequencies. For example, Frequency 4 (x10^14) corresponds to 750nm, frequency 8 (x10^14) corresponds to 370nm.

I have the data of wavelength in column I and frequency in column M. The output (y-axis) Energy Joules is in column P.

Note I dont think I should use a secondary axis, since this is same datapoint, just mapped to two different versions of input.

enter image description here

Comment: Why not have two charts overlaid with parts transparent.

Comment: hmm is there no way to do it directly in excel? Otherwise I could do it in illustrator as well

Comment: Did you tag illustrator?

Comment: I want to do it in excel. doing it in illustrator is like doing it in paint....